# Composer not installing dependencies

Tags: composer-php

I installed the package [mageplaza/module-smtp](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/tree/master). It has the package **mageplaza/module-core** as requirement. ([composer.json](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/blob/master/composer.json))

As I install the package with: `composer require mageplaza/module-smtp` it just installed that package and ignores the **mageplaza/module-core** dependency.

So I had to install it manually with: `composer require mageplaza/module-core`

Why do I need to install dependencies manually?

Comment: Did you check whether `mageplaza/module-core`  was installed through any other dependency? Can you share a minimal working example for your `composer.json`  that helps to understand the problem?

Comment: "Why do I need to install dependencies manually?" - you don't have to. Composer takes care of this, and I've never seen any case in the last years where this works otherwise

Comment: @NicoHaase the example is linked in my question already.

Comment: @Black: Not really, as at least I find this hard to reproduce: `rm -rf ./*; composer -n -q --no-scripts require --no-plugins mageplaza/module-smtp; composer -n --no-ansi show -N | grep core` gives `mageplaza/module-core` (run this in an empty, temporary directory)

Comment: "the example is linked in my question already" - no, it's not. You haven't shared any `composer.json` from your project yet, and as a long-time user of SO, you should know that all clarification should be part of the question without the need to look at external ressources

Comment: My composer.json requires authentification from magento 2 enterprise and I doubt that it will be useful for you.

Comment: Feel free to create a minimal example otherwise